# call ff_print_debug_info2 outside of mpegvideo.c file

Tags: c, ffmpeg

I want `void ff_print_debug_info2(...)` to be called outside of mpegvideo.c file. For instance, I want to call this function inside the following code snippet:

```
static int decode_packet(int *got_frame, int cached)
{
    int ret = 0;
    int decoded = pkt.size;
    *got_frame = 0;
    if (pkt.stream_index == video_stream_idx) {
        /* decode video frame */
        ret = avcodec_decode_video2(video_dec_ctx, frame, got_frame, &pkt);
        if (ret < 0) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error decoding video frame (%s)\n", av_err2str(ret));
            return ret;
        }
        if (*got_frame) {
/*here I want to print debug info*/
//void ff_print_debug_info2(AVCodecContext *avctx, AVFrame *pict, uint8_t *mbskip_table, uint32_t *mbtype_table, int8_t *qscale_table, int16_t (*motion_val[2])[2], int *low_delay, int mb_width, int mb_height, int mb_stride, int quarter_sample)     
        }
    }
    return decoded;
}
```

I wonder if it's possible, and how shall I pass parameters into `void ff_print_debug_info2(...)`?

ps: parameters I already know: 
1.`AVCodecContext *avctx`: `video_dec_ctx`
2.`AVFrame *pict`: `frame`
3.`int8_t *qscale_table`: `frame->qscale_table`.
How about the others?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function is already [called](https://www.ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/h264_8c_source.html#l01547) for you by the H264 decoder. It is unsupported by any other decoder and will cause crashes. You should never need to call it manually. If you're not seeing any debug information printed on the frame after H264 frame decoding, try to use:

```
avctx->debug |= FF_DEBUG_VIS_QP |
                FF_DEBUG_VIS_MB_TYPE |
                FF_DEBUG_SKIP |
                FF_DEBUG_QP |
                FF_DEBUG_MB_TYPE;
avctx->debug_mv = FF_DEBUG_VIS_MV_P_FOR |
                  FF_DEBUG_VIS_MV_B_FOR |
                  FF_DEBUG_VIS_MV_B_BACK;
```

after (thanks for the correction!) your call to `avcodec_open2()`. After that, you should see the appropriate debug information printed on the frame (`*_VIS_*`) or on the terminal (the others).

These flags are also supported by the MPEG-1/2/4 decoders, although they are implemented through a different function (`ff_print_debug_info()`).

Comment: It worked well. Just to correct you a tiny mistake: these flags should be set after calling avcodec_open2() not before, otherwise I experienced segmentation fault... and one should also choose correct log level: av_log_set_level(48) in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [on the manual](https://fossies.org/dox/MPlayer-1.3.0/mpegvideo_8h.html#ad5717ea71f6e43cec54ae3149d08ddf6) you can use outside `mpegvideo.c` scope.

The function `ff_print_debug_info2` is exported with `mpegvideo.h`

So just

```
#include <mpegvideo.h>
```

or

```
#include "mpegvideo..h"
```

in source file where function has to be used.

Comment: how to determine parameters when I call the function? eg. uint8_t *mbskip_table, uint32_t *mbtype_table, int16_t (*motion_val[2])[2], int *low_delay, int mb_width, int mb_height, etc...

Comment: those parameters are variables determined at runtime... I've look up the linked man, there's little relevant info.

Comment: That function is designed to do something with those vars. If you do not understand what those var are why do you want to call that function?

Comment: I want them to be printed out so I can find some clue how decoding works at macroblock level.